# Paperclip, getting "undefined method error" :photo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a photo stored on s3 and when I am trying to display a photo, the method is not defined.

Why is has_attached_file not defining :photo here?

My model:

```
has_attached_file :photo,
                  :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", 
                  :thumb => "100x100>" },
                  :storage => :s3,
                  :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/aws.yml",
                  :s3_region => 'US Standard'
```

My controller:

```
@products = Store.all

private
  def product_params
    params.require(:store).permit(:id, :name, :photo)
  end
```

My view:

```
<%= image_tag @products.photo.url %>
```

My schema (just to show the paperclip migration worked):

```
create_table "stores", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name",               limit: 255

    t.string   "photo_file_name"
    t.string   "photo_content_type"
    t.integer  "photo_file_size"
    t.datetime "photo_updated_at"
  end
```

I forgot to mention: my form is saving the photo to my S3 bucket using the :photo param, it is just not rendering in my view with this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a typo in your `view`:

`@products` is an `array of objects` not an object you can call `photo` on an `object`.

please change you code accordingly you can get the photo by calling `@products[0].photo.url`

Comment: Actually I am in the Store model...I just have a @products instance of Store.

Comment: You're amazing! thank you! I knew it was an array but wasn't really sure what paperclip was doing